# Is R 4.0.2 Slower than R 3.5.2?

Tags: r, dplyr, rodbc

I've just upgraded from R 3.5.2 to R 4.0.2.

At first glance it seems quite slow compared to what I had previously experienced. I'm working with a particular script, which mostly involves some `dplyr` queries and sending a data frame to MS Access using `RODBC::sqlSave()`, if that helps. Also some string functions like `substr()` and some data transformations using `as.Date()`.

Some unfamiliar messages popping up when running `dplyr` queries but they still seem to work (albeit rather slowly).

Has anyone else experienced this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've just updated and a ran a project I've been working on. It's gone from taking a couple of minutes to run, to a few seconds. Way faster for me! Similar to you its largely dplyr and a few other little bits.

Comment: Hmm strange... 